# No audio in rendered video if audio is in sequencer while video stuff is in Compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, video-sequence-editor, video, audio

I noticed that if I use the compositor, I cannot get anything in the Sequencer included in the output even if *Sequencer* is ticked in the lower right corner. But that's okay for the Video and Image Sequence stuff because I just add them as a nodes in the Compositor and mix their *Image* sockets together. But I don't understand how the audio comes into play. The only place I can place the Audio is in the Sequencer. But even if *Audio Codec* is set from *No Audio* to *MP3* or *AAC*, there is still no Audio in the final output. It seems like Blender is ignoring whatever is in the *Sequencer* if I use the Compositor. How do I integrate the sound into the final video output?

[image]

Comment: Does the audio play in the editor? I created a similar setup to yours, but when I render an animation it has audio. Can you open the sidebar in the sequencer by pressing N and look if there under _Sound_ the _Volume_ setting is at 0 (although the waveform does not look like it)? Because the _Volume_ value in the Output_ properties is not the only one where you could have muted the sound.

Comment: Hi @GordonBrinkmann thank you for your time testing. I was surprised because now suddenly my video has audio.. I duno what I did, it just suddenly worked. oops. Well at least I have got confirmation that this should definitely work.

Comment: Maybe there was just some problem when it rendered the video file.

Comment: When rendering plain videos with image sequences, does it matter if I use Eevee or Cycles and does the sample rate matter? What is the recommended samples for plain images?

Comment: Don't know, I never use Eevee for rendering. Also what do you mean with recommended samples for plain images? As much samples as you want, depending on how long you would accept an image to render and how much noise is acceptable for you or how many samples you need so that denoising does not look too bad... and this can vary a lot from scene to scene.

Comment: but there is no real rendering with lights involved in rendering an image sequence since these frames have already been rendered for me. what i did was render the image sequence out and open a new file and import as image sequence. then render it again on top of a video. so i'm not sure if using eevee or cycles makes any difference in that case since no lighting is involved.

Comment: Oh, you are talking about a pre-rendered image sequence. As far as I've experienced it, the samples do not really matter in that case. As I said, I usually do not render in Eevee. Just set the samples to something low like 1 or 5 or whatever and use the render engine which renders this setup the quickest by testing with single frames.